# user defined function for based on the current row and the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I am working on an automation task in python. I want a column 'result' wherein it should contain '1' if the column 'Battery' contains 'Discharge' and the previous row contains 'None' else it should contain '0'

The 1st row by default should contain 0.

The excel formula is

> =IF(AND(AD2="None",AD3="Discharge"),1,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `np.where()` for setting the condition, and then force the first row to `0`:

```
import numpy as np

df['result'] = np.where(
    (df.Battery=='Discharge') & (df.Battery.shift()=='None'),
    1,
    0
)

df['result'].iloc[0] = 0
```